# Django - Iterating over list in template

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

Currently trying to iterate over a list using Django templating.
What I am trying to achieve is having multiple row with three columns. The current logic creates a one row with around every third card element.

What would be the best approach for creating each row w/ three columns?

```
{% extends "stockwatcher/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  {% for stock in stocks %}
    {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 or forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}
    <div class="row">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="card text-white bg-info mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">{{stock.transaction_date}}</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ stock.id }} {{stock.ticker}} </h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{stock.senator}} - {{stock.type}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 or forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}
    </div> 
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use row div outside the for loop and bootstrap classes will handle the rest for you. You can also use  `{% empty %}` tag to handle empty list.

```
{% extends "stockwatcher/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    {% for stock in stocks %}
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="card text-white bg-info mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">{{stock.transaction_date}}</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ stock.id }} {{stock.ticker}} </h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{stock.senator}} - {{stock.type}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% empty %}
        No items
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```